# Issue with Proxy Configuration in Blackbox Exporter

Tags: http, prometheus, monitoring, endpoint, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Hello StackOverFlow Community,

I’m facing an issue with configuring a proxy in the Blackbox Exporter.

Despite setting the **proxy_url** parameter and enabling **proxy_from_environment** in the blackbox.yml file, the Blackbox Exporter still fails to use the proxy, resulting in timeout errors.

Additionally, I have set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables in the Docker Compose file, and confirmed their presence in the running container.

Any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

balckbox.yml file:

modules:
http_2xx:
prober: http
timeout: 5s
http:
proxy_url: “http://proxy-site:3128”
proxy_from_environment: true
skip_resolve_phase_with_proxy: true
valid_http_versions: [HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2]
valid_status_codes: [200, 204]
method: GET
tls_config:
insecure_skip_verify: true